# Option element that is equal to ng-model is not showing on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

This stores an option value in localStorage and it works, but my problem is that the selected option does not show when the page refreshes. I've tried ng-selected and ng-class with no luck.

index.html

```
     <select ng-change='taskTimer(duration)' ng-model='duration'>
     <option ng-repeat='TO in timeOptions'
          ng-selected='duration'>{{TO}}</option>
          {{TO}}</option>
     </select>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.timeOptions = [15, 30, 45, 60];
```

Comment: how does it store into localStorage?

Comment: please show all relevant code relating to getting and setting the storage

Comment: why not use ngOption?